# Create a new column in Pandas Dataframe based on the 'NaN' values in another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe:

```
A B
1 NaN
2 3
4 NaN
5 NaN
6 7
```

I want to create a new column `C` containing the value from `B` that aren't NaN, otherwise the values from `A`. This would be a simple matter in Excel; is it easy in Pandas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's simple. Use [`pandas.Series.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html):

```
df['C'] = df['A'].where(df['B'].isna(), df['B'])
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   A    B  C
0  1  NaN  1
1  2  3.0  3
2  4  NaN  4
3  5  NaN  5
4  6  7.0  7
```

A bit cleaner:

```
df.C = df.A.where(df.B.isna(), df.B)
```

Alternatively:

```
df.C = df.B.where(df.B.notna(), df.A)
```